# IAP Non consumable after 7 days free trial

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to implement IAP in my application but the client says that **application will be run as the free trial in the first week** after installation then **it must take the charge from IAP** else the application will show the popup.

**Q1: Can we implement this from the Apple guideline?**